# Keras, tape.gradient return None values

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to retrieve the gradient values computed by Tensorflow. The loss value that I pass to the **tape.gradient** function, is based on some values from the different layers of my network controller (I am using the network as a controller for some NAS algorithm, but it's not important).
Here is the part of my code where I retrieve values (a softmax value) from layers, add them up and pass the sum (*loss_value*) to the **tape.gradient** function:

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:



   # FEEDFORWARD
    inp = controller.input  # input placeholder
    outputs = [layer.output for layer in controller.layers if ( layer.__class__.__name__ == "Dense" or layer.__class__.__name__ == "Lambda" )]  # all layer outputs
    functor = K.function([inp], outputs )   # evaluation function
    test = np.random.random((1,1))[np.newaxis,...]
    layer_outs = functor([test]) # Here are all the outputs of all the layers


    ### retrieve some values from the RNN controller layers in order to comute a loss 

    log_proba = 0
    loss_value = 0

    # loop over each layer (choice)
    for i in range(0, len(layer_outs), 2):

        # Class that was chosen by the RNN
        classe = layer_outs[i+1][0][0]

        # Proba of having chosen class 'classe' knowing the previous choices
        proba = layer_outs[i][0][0][layer_outs[i+1][0][0]]
        log_proba = tf.math.log(proba)
      
    loss_value += log_proba

### Compute the gradients of the trainable weights w.r.t loss_value
grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, controller.trainable_weights)

print(grads)
```

Which always print **None** values.

You can find the complete code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hGd_IDpNmKPTCShehgTQ_SvmSrn9XpYo?usp=sharing) on Google Colab and change it.

Thank you

Comment: You are not doing the computation inside the GradientTape correctly, you need to pass an input through your model, not using K.function

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thank you, I am using K.function to retrieve the outputs of all the layers, is there another way to do it ?